How to correctly get all properties of a specific key type from an interface in TypeScript?
When working with arrays, the following is valid:
const MyArray = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 15 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 23 },
  { name: "Eve", age: 38 },
];
 
type Person = typeof MyArray[number];

Then I tried the same idea with interfaces:
interface A {
  a: number;
}

type PropertiesTypeByString = A[string]

but I got an error:
Type 'A' has no matching index signature for type 'string'.

Given that I want to get all the properties of the key type string, what should I do?

?? Because A is a type and not a value. You're asking "why indexed access types" don't work, but they work fine. What's not "working" is typeof. Don't write typeof A, just write A.  The type is A[string].  Except it's not, because string isn't a key of A, so you're looking for A['a'] or something?  What's the... oh, look, you're editing the question to ask multiple things at once. Please [edit] this to be a single question about a single problem.

... so this is an XY problem? You want to "get all the properties of the key type string"? Maybe [edit] the question so that this is the title and then your question could briefly mention your failed attempts.  The answer here is either A[keyof A] or A[string & keyof A] depending how desperately you need to ignore non-string keys. Does that fully address the question? Or am I missing something?

@jcalz: Oh, I thought that string was enough and didn't realize that I should use string literal types for each of the keys. The one A[string & keyof A] solves my updated question. If every string literal type is a subtype of string, then why I cannot just use string as the index here?

If you write T[K] then K has to be a subtype of keyof T, not vice versa. If you have an object a of type A, and a key k of type string, it's a mistake to write a[k] in TypeScript, because that key might very well not appear in the object. So you can't write A[string] either. TS complains because string is not a key of A. And if it didn't complain, A[string] would probably be unknown because there are all sorts of possible keys a value of type A might have.

If you want to index into an object type A, the key needs to be assignable to keyof A (using the keyof type operator).  Since A doesn't have a string index signature, you can't write A[string].  Instead, you can intersect keyof A with string to get "all the keys of A of type string:
const sym = Symbol();
interface A {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
  3: Date; // numeric key, not string
  [sym]: Element // symbol key, not string
}

type PropertiesTypeByString  = A[keyof A & string];
//   ^? type PropertiesTypeByString  = number | boolean

Playground link to code

You can filter out keys that don't match a specific type (e. g. string) with a Mapped Type and Key Mapping. If a key K extends string it is kept in the object otherwise it is removed by remapping it to never.
interface A {
  a: number;
  1: string;
}

type KeysOfType<T, U extends PropertyKey> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as K extends U ? K : never]: T[K];
};
type Result = KeysOfType<A, string>;
//   ^? type Result = "a"

TypeScript Playground

Given the context of the question, another thing you presumably misunderstand is that typeof MyArray[number] doesn't really have anything to do with keys of type number. The indexing with number only means it doesn't matter which item of an array is indexed as they are all the same. So, instead of typeof MyArray[0] or typeof MyArray[1] you can simply use number.

I think this isn't what's being asked (although KeysOfA is a misleading name in OP's question). It's really just looking for indexed accesses (keys of type string, not values of type string).

Hmm... How to correctly get all properties of a specific key type... sounded very unambiguously to me. Now I'm not sure anymore either.

The word "key" in there is what makes the difference. Properties of a specific key type. From my requests for clarification in the comments, it's clear enough that OP is really just trying to do indexed accesses.

Isn't a key type the type of a key (=PropertyKey)? Anyway, after reading the comments it's clear that you're right (as always ;D). I'll keep my answer undeleted, unless the OP is edited accordingly. It might be useful for future readers.

Yup, my naming is the problem. I should name it PropertiesOfKeyType or something. If you don't mind, I will update my question. Apologies for this.

I don't understand the second part of your answer. If string is not valid for A[string] because it includes (many) non-existence keys like 'b', then why number won't cause an issue for MyArray[number]? For example, MyArray[4] is an invalid access.

number only works when indexing an array type. A TypeScript array type (in comparison to a tuple) does not have a fixed length. typeof MyArray is just { name: string; age: number; }[]. The runtime variable array contains 3 item but on type level there is no information about that. Theoretically the array could have any length. Therefore, it is often more precise to index with number than to use random indexes that all index the same type. FYI typeof MyArray[4] (and also 3 or 23802302) are valid. Try it.
